# iPhone codesign Missing Resources

Tags: iphone, codesign

I'm trying to get my ad hoc build distributed but have started experiencing problems. It used to work up until around a week ago, but now ITunes gives an 0x8008017 error when I try to Sync.

I've narrowed it down by using the iPhone Configuration Utility and then discovering the error seems to be coming from a failed code sign. I've ran codesign -vvvv myApp.app and the outup lists a load of missing resources from my Help documents (from my Apps Resource folder). each missing resource begins ._ so for my index page:

01 - Index.html

the codesign is also expecting: ._01 - Index.html

It also has the existing file listed (as it should) but fails because all ._files are not included in the app.

I've looked through my projects directory and can't find any files beginning with ._ so am not sure where the codesigner is getting these filenames from, but they are included every build, after a clean or an Xcode restart.

All the resources that are causing problems are all recently updated files that I copied over the old resources at the beginning of the week; might this be something to do with it?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do one of these:

- copy those files with an Xcode Copy Files phase, which should Do The Right Thing by default, or
- exclude resource forks and `._*` files if you copy through a script, or
- make sure you build on HFS volumes (where `._*` files are not generated for resource forks).

Sounds like your partition type is generating resource-fork files which are also being signed as separate files in the bundle, rather than as part of the original files (which is bad); and then, they're also not getting copied (if you use Finder zipping, they'll be removed and set aside in a different portion of the Zip file, IIRC), again bad. Avoid having them in the bundle, so they don't get signed and you don't have to wade through this mess :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - is it obvious that I'm extremely new to Mac development (or general usage) ;)  

So what would my next move be? Move the all the resources to another directory and then use a Copy Files phase to bring them back into the project? Or have Bad Things already happened...

Comment: Sorted it now :) Thanks for the heads up!